# Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, karma-jasmine

I am testing angular app with jasmine. In the test file, I have injected google maps module like this:

```
beforeEach(module('uiGmapgoogle-maps'));
```

**uiGmapgoogle-maps** is also added as a dependency of app module of my application.

In files array of karma.conf.js file, I have added

```
'app/lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js',
```

I am trying to test a service existence, that have **uiGmapGoogleMapApi** as dependency of that service.

I am testing this service (geoLocationService) with this code.

```
 beforeEach(inject(function(_geoLocationService_) {
    geoLocationFactory = _geoLocationService_;

}));

it('geoLocationFactory should be defined.', function () {
    expect(geoLocationFactory).toBeDefined();
});
```

On **expect(geoLocationFactory).toBeDefined();** it is giving me an error like:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'uiGmapgoogle-maps' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dep
endencies as the second argument.
```